# Cant start Ubuntu from dvd device

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, dvd

I am a long time user of Ubuntu and I'm trying to get it runnning on this pc with preloaded windows 8.1

I have disabled secure boot and dealt with UEFI, when I enter the BIOS I have moved CD/DVD boot first and hard disk to last. I have properly burned the ISO file having the contents in the CD, which was done through windows 8.1. I restart the computer and press F12 to get to the boot options, no other option shows up except for two Windows Boot Managers. I have attempted this install method multiple times and any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

(Update) after setting the boot priority in the same restart, I am now getting this result:

[image]

Comment: On my ASUS Win 8.1 machine, the boot order settings in the UEFI BIOS do not persist through a reboot.  I have to enter the BIOS and insert the USB, and add the USB as a boot option on the same computer restart, and it will boot off USB.  If I change the options, then reboot, it does not work.  I do not know, but perhaps  it is the same with DVD.  So try this: 1) Reboot 2)enter the BIOS 3) set DVD first 4) allow boot to continue

Comment: I was able to leave Secure Boot enabled but I had to turn off Fast Boot because my Ubuntu install was on a different physical hard drive.

Comment: @organicMarble I managed to get a new result with this, displayed here [link](http://imgur.com/YYvRhSR). It seems to allude that my DVD is improperly formatted but I am pretty sure everything is in order (I followed instructions at [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto))

Comment: That does look like the media is not bootable.  Is it possible to try it in a different PC?  Or boot off USB?

Comment: One other thought: is this a 64 bit Ubuntu?  It has to be, to work with UEFI.

Comment: Can you [verify the integrity](//help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) of the data on the boot medium (the DVD in question)?

Comment: It is 64 bit and i just checked the integrity and everything checks out, I'm going to now attempt with a flash drive will post results.

Comment: If anything else, Use dd to copy the iso to a flash drive and use UEFI, it's not much, if any more secure, but it works. 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/562982/ubuntu-14-04-single-boot-with-uefi-mode-enabled/563004#563004

Comment: After finally obtaining a flash drive, it now works perfectly, not quite sure what was wrong with the cd drive but, thanks for all your help guys.

Answer (score 2):

First, it's unclear what you mean that you "dealt with UEFI." There's a ***LOT*** of misinformation floating around about EFI-mode booting, so a vague statement that you "dealt with" it could mean that you've followed appropriate advice or that you've followed any of the many (in fact, perhaps *more* numerous than correct) pages that present iffy or flat-out wrong information. [My Web page on Linux UEFI installations](http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/) is accurate, to the best of my knowledge, but is not Ubuntu-specific. The [Ubuntu wiki page on UEFI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) is also reasonably accurate, although I haven't studied it in depth.

Second, one very common problem with creating Ubuntu installation optical discs is accidentally creating a disc that contains the `.iso` file, rather than burning the `.iso` file as a disc image. If you open the disc you burned in Windows and see a single `.iso` file as its contents, it's burned incorrectly; you should see over a dozen files and directories:

```
autorun.inf  casper  EFI      isolinux    pics  preseed             ubuntu
boot         dists   install  md5sum.txt  pool  README.diskdefines  wubi.exe
```

That's what's on a 14.10 AMD64 desktop image. Other architectures and versions may vary a bit.