# Install ubuntu 14.04 alone in Lenovo B575

Tags: uefi, boot-repair

I remove windows 7 in Lenovo B575 and installed ubuntu 14.04 but seems like it have UEFI enabled. I was unaware of it before so to do anything from windows is now not possible. I search for everything and tried everything possible but I am not able to boot from ubuntu.

I have read this link

[Ubuntu 14.04 single-boot with UEFI-mode enabled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/562982/ubuntu-14-04-single-boot-with-uefi-mode-enabled#)

I followed it but this also didn't work.

I tried to boot-repair, no luck. Every post from ubuntu is confusing and is not straight forward for me.

Can someone please just write the steps (with no long description) to solve this?

Also, I have already tried making /boot/efi partition but it also didn't work.

Comment: I had to undergo your same situation a few days ago. What I did was that I Switched to MBR tables, and that fixed everything. Should I write the steps for you? Also what is your PC's brand?

Comment: yes I would love to give it a try. its Lenovo B575

Comment: what settings do you have in Bios? On Levono machines you need to start with a special bottom on the right side of the machine to get access. http://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/lenovo_g_z_series_ug_english.pdf See boot options into the bios. I also had problem to enable the hardrive but using gparted I could reset the harddrive, and did not get any errors at installation.

Comment: It's unclear what you've done or what your problem is. You state that you removed Windows, but then say "...to do anything from windows is now not possible." Of course; if you removed Windows, using it becomes impossible. Is lack of Windows the main problem? You later also say you can't boot Ubuntu, but you haven't provided any diagnostic information, such as the URL that Boot Repair provides. Without such detailed diagnostic information, any help offered will be nothing but guesswork.

Comment: paste.ubuntu.com/11470714

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: If you choose to do this, all data stored on your HDD will be lost. You should continue this only if you donot have any data, or you have taken Backups. Also there could be better ways of doing this, and do this only as a last resort. If you do this, you won't be abole to dual boot with newer versions of Windows anymore.

Upong googling a bit I found that UEFI implemented on Lenovo B757 model laptops are quite buggy. Also it came with Windows 7 pre installed usinh MBR patition table. Since you are not interested in Windows, you must change back to MBR and your problems should be solved.

I am assuming that you have a live CD/USB from which you installed Ubuntu. Load Ubuntu live environment from the CD. When you have booted into the desktop, press `Ctrl + Alt + T` to open a terminal. Type in:

```
sudo gparted
```

You have opened the Partitioning tool. make sure that your HDD is selected in the top right corner(if I remember correctly). If any of the listed partitions are mounted, then unmount them. Select `Device->Create Partition Table`. Choose `ms-dos`. Now you need to do the partitioning again from the same tool.

Finally when you are done, click Apply or the Green Tick Mark.

Exit gparted, install Ubuntu again. You are almost over, but don't forget this last step, or your system won't boot. Go to BIOS and choose `Legacy` instead of `UEFI`.

Now your system should boot!

Comment: There's likely no need to really do this...

Comment: The thing is that I have already installed ubuntu and the problem as far as I know is in bios option. There is no option to change UEFI mode to legacy mode.

Comment: @Err0rr, are you sure that your laptop is UEFI capable? How do you know? If it was not UEFI capable, it would be in legacy mode and it is not booting because you did UEFI partitioning which your laptop doesn't recognize. If this is the case, my answer is the only way to fix it, I believe...

Comment: @Err0rr, according to [this](http://www.eightforums.com/installation-setup/27472-cant-install-windows-8-1-non-uefi-laptop.html) guy, your laptop is not UEFI.

Comment: if UEFI is enabled then the boot screen will be different. I knew by that way
http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-lbCXvuI3flU/UclTr4kFwOI/AAAAAAAAARA/1x7Z6vp0RZc/s400/Screenshot+from+2013-06-25+16:23:08.png

If not enabled then looks like below link
http://i.stack.imgur.com/ljHCe.png

Comment: @Err0rr, The first image is that of the GRUB boot menu, which will look the same weather you use UEFI or not. I've [googled a bit more](https://www.google.co.in/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=lenovo+b575+uefi&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=d7JqVc-jOMecuQToroLQBw), and found out that lenovo's UEFI implementation for your laptop is quite buggy. Better stick with MBR!

Comment: okay what is the solution for this then?

Comment: My answer dude! Give it a try! Do you have any data to back up?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24309/discussion-between-err0rr-and-user3073656).

Comment: There is no option to change in legacy mode

Comment: Sorry there is only one partition and is not allowing me to create partition table. it says "A new partition table cannot be created when there are acive partitions. ..."

Comment: @Err0rr, that's why you should unmount all partition. Right click all partitions and unmount if they are mounted.

Comment: @user3073656 many many thanks for your support but I am unable to umount the devices. I will install and continue using windows 7. Thank you all.